# linkedin email address not recieved using python socail auth

Tags: django, linkedin-api, python-social-auth

I have my `linkedin` scope set as follows:

`SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_SCOPE = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress']`

When I try logging in using `python social auth` then an exception is raised which is defined in my model:

```
if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
```

while logging in with `facebook` and `google` work fine but not `linkedin`

The error means it does not have email field in it. I am working on my `localhost`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like for `linkedin` we need to specify field selectors in order to get email address and other information from it unlike facebook and google. This is what i was missing:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_FIELD_SELECTORS = ['email-address']
```